# how to slide from a generic home page to nestedlist layout in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, nested-lists

I'm starting to use sencha touch.   I've been able to create a nestedlist layout where clicking on a leaf element triggers a getdetailcard.   Now I want to do something that's kind of the reverse of that.

I want to now create a home page with nothing on it but a logo.  WHen user clicks on logo, the layout scrolls to a nested list of items.

can someone point me to the relevant documentation or show me sample code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add panel card to your viewport and then on logo tap change the active item.

Here is sample code:

```
   var data = {
    text: 'Groceries',
    items: [{
        text: 'Drinks',
        items: [{
            text: 'Water',
            items: [{
                text: 'Sparkling',
                leaf: true
            }]
        }]
    }]
};
Ext.regModel('ListItem', {
    fields: [{name: 'text', type: 'string'}]
});
var store = new Ext.data.TreeStore({
    model: 'ListItem',
    root: data,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        reader: {
            type: 'tree',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});
var nestedList = new Ext.NestedList({
    title: 'Groceries',
    displayField: 'text',
    store: store
});

var MyApp = new Ext.Application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function() {
        MyApp.views.viewport = new Ext.Panel({
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: 'card',
            cardAnimation: 'slide',
            items: [
                {
                xtype: 'panel',
                    html:'<img src="https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png">',
                    listeners:{
                        el:{tap:function(){MyApp.views.viewport.setActiveItem(1,{type:'slide',direction:'left'});}}
                    }
                },
              nestedList
            ]
        });
    }
});
```